# Sprite sheet in Unity2D URP compressing too much?

Tags: unity-game-engine, sprite, pixel, urp

Im using URP on unity2d. I managed to set up a good color swap thing for one of my sprites. So I can change all of the colors individually to anything I want.

But I need animations on this sprite and different states of beings. So I tried to do the same thing in URP, but instead of one sprite, a sprite sheet, so I can animate my sprite and change its state of being while keeping the colors I want,

But, when I import the sprite sheet in the texture2D in the universal render pipeline area, the sprite sheet gets super compressed, making it impossible to replace colors because it’s no longer crisp pixel art. One sprite works perfectly, a sprite sheet screws everything up.

I thought ok maybe it’s the size, I try to change size but changing size decompress pixel art creating same problem! How do I make the space of the texture2D thing on URP bigger so my sprite sheet not get compressed?

Please help

Comment: https://www.reddit.com/r/Unity2D/

Comment: ok for anyone else having the same problem its because my spritesheet exceeded unity's 2048 limit so unity was decompressing it thus causing it to be even MORE compressed in URP